# How can I plot a 2d function with coordinate system (e.g. Sin(x)) in Flutter's dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I Draw and animate something like this in Flutter?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need seems just a canvas. With a canvas, you can draw anything you'd like to, and animate it by redraw on time.

Canvas is supported in Flutter, by extending *CustomPaint*, 
Like this:

```
class SinCanvas extends StatelessWidget {
  const SinCanvas({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: CustomPaint(
        size:Size(600,400),
        painter: SinPainter()
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SinPainter extends CustomPainter{
  @override void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size){
    final midY = size.height/2;
    final paint = Paint()..style = PaintingStyle.fill
    ..color = Colors.black;
    canvas.drawLine(Offset(0,midY), Offset(size.width,midY), paint);
    var pt = Offset(0,midY);
    for(double i=0;i<600;i+=0.1){
      final npt = Offset(i,midY-sin(i/50)*100);
      canvas.drawLine(pt, npt, paint);
      pt = npt;
    }
  }
  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

To animate, you can change the StatelessWidget to a StatefulWidget, and update the graphics with State.

Hope this solves your question.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks so much!